# How to manage Apache (httpd) with Supervisord properly in a Docker?

Tags: apache, docker, centos, centos6, supervisord

I am trying to build a Docker image with Apache (httpd) and PHP 5.3.3. The image is based on a [CentOS 6 && Supervisord](https://hub.docker.com/r/reynierpm/centos6-supervisord/) that I have made. So far everything is working "fine" (and this means no issues during build process) but I am having some issues with Apache and Supervisord. Why? Because I think the image based on `reynierpm/centos6-supervisord` is already starting Apache and then Supervisord is trying to do the same thing. Here is a log of what I am getting when I start my stack using `docker-compose up`:

```
webserver_1  | 2018-02-03 19:29:52,882 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
webserver_1  | 2018-02-03 19:29:52,882 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor.d/httpd.conf" during parsing
webserver_1  | 2018-02-03 19:29:52,913 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
webserver_1  | 2018-02-03 19:29:52,920 INFO supervisord started with pid 8
webserver_1  | 2018-02-03 19:29:53,923 INFO spawned: 'httpd' with pid 11
webserver_1  | 2018-02-03 19:29:53,928 INFO spawned: 'httpd-reload' with pid 12
webserver_1  | 2018-02-03 19:29:53,964 DEBG 'httpd' stderr output:
webserver_1  | httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.18.0.2 for ServerName
webserver_1  |
webserver_1  | 2018-02-03 19:29:53,965 DEBG fd 9 closed, stopped monitoring <POutputDispatcher at 41891168 for <Subprocess at 140421355793008 with name httpd in state STARTING> (stderr)>
webserver_1  | 2018-02-03 19:29:53,979 DEBG fd 7 closed, stopped monitoring <POutputDispatcher at 41890736 for <Subprocess at 140421355793008 with name httpd in state STARTING> (stdout)>
webserver_1  | 2018-02-03 19:29:53,980 INFO exited: httpd (exit status 0; not expected)
webserver_1  | 2018-02-03 19:29:53,981 DEBG received SIGCLD indicating a child quit
webserver_1  | 2018-02-03 19:29:54,983 INFO spawned: 'httpd' with pid 23
webserver_1  | 2018-02-03 19:29:54,985 INFO success: httpd-reload entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
```

I have created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/reypm/e0730981f6849d843a40143ffc52f019) having the Dockerfile and the `httpd.conf` file read by Supervisord, what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: why do you need supervisor if you run just apache inside the container? your supervisor config loads two apps, httpd and httpd-reload on startup... i think you should avoid supervisor as much as possible, because when you would scale your app you still scale the supervisor and not just apache...

Comment: @MazelTov well I was trying to avoid a container per app but that doesn't make to much sense, that's exactly one of the things what Docker is for. And yes I'd my suspicious about Supervisord trying to start Apache once again.